# How do I access my user in a valid JWT for unprotected routes?

Tags: jwt, controller, nestjs, authorization, guard

I'm using NestJS 10 with TypeORM 0.3.17.  I have this method in my controller

```
  @UseGuards(AccessTokenGuard)
  @Post()
  create(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Body() createOrderDto: CreateOrderDto,
  ): Promise<Order> {
    const userId = req.user['sub'];
    return this.ordersService.create(userId, createOrderDto);
  }
```

and this is how the guard is defined

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class AccessTokenGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}
```

My question is, what if I want to unprotect the route (it is not required to submit a valid JWT token to access the route), but I would like to access the user if there is a valid JWT submitted.  I'm noticing that if I remove the

```
@UseGuards(AccessTokenGuard)
```

line, I can't get access to the "req.user['sub']" object anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.user` is populated by parsing the `JWT` that is sent which is what `passport-jwt` is doing. If you don't call to the `AccessTokenGuard` then the jwt is never parsed and `req.user` is never populated. If you want, you can make an `OptionalTokenGuard` that calls to the `canActivate` of `AuthGuard('jwt')` but returns `true` regardless the outcome, so that `req.user` *might* be populated. This would look something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class OptionalTokenGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    await super.canActivate(context);
    return true;
  }
}
```